# Powershell output doesn't display until going through loop again or loop ends

Tags: powershell, loops, output

I am writing a powershell script for my college Windows Client OS class and am having an issue with some of the output not displaying correctly. I am very new to powershell scripting and don't even know what they issue could be. The code is in a do/while loop and a switch to make a menu, but the output doesn't display when you select the menu option. However, when you select the menu option again it displays some of the information twice, then when selecting the option a third time displays the information once, but without the header and continues to do so every time after that.

This is the code:

```
cls
Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk | Select DeviceID,
@{Name="Size";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}},
@{Name="Free Space";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1GB,2)}}
Sort FreeGB | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

Again this is in a switch that is in a do while loop.

The first time running it it displays nothing, the second time or exiting the loop it displays this:
DeviceID Size Free Space
C:-------------20----------2.29
D:--------------0---------------0
C:-------------20----------2.29
D:--------------0---------------0

(Ignore the dashes I just don't know how to format on this site)
The Third time it displays the info once, but without the header names above it.

I don't really know how to fix this and I've been looking for an hour, not that I would really know what I'm looking for anyway, any hints?

**EDIT:**
Here is the entire loop:

```
do {

cls
Show-Menu   
$input = Read-Host "Select 1-9"
switch ($input)   
{
    '1' {
        cls
        Write-Host "Computer Name:" $env:computername | Select-Object
        Write-Host "OS Version:" ([Environment]::OSVersion.VersionString) 
    }
    '2' { # Modified From: https://www.petri.com/checking-system-drive-free-space-with-wmi-and-powershell
        cls
        Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk | Select DeviceID,
        @{Name="Size";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}},
        @{Name="Free Space";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1GB,2)}}
    }
    '3' {

    }
    '4' {

    }
    '5' {

    }
    '6' {

    }
    '7' {

    }
    '8' {

    }
    '9' {
        return
    }
}
pause } while ($input -ne '9')
```

Comment: I'd like to see more of the code. What you have posted seems to work as intended. If I take that code and run it within a loop, it will output one table to the console with the same rows repeated as many times as the loop iterates.

Comment: [1] you are missing a pipe a the end of line #4 - so the `Sort-Object` & `Format-Table` calls do _nothing_. [*grin*] [2] your command works _every time for me_. ///// so ... as AdminOfThings asked ... is there more code somewhere that you left out? ///// also, the `Format-Table` cmdlet is totally unneeded. your `Select-Object` call already sets things up for display.

Comment: presuming you have a `Write-Host` or `Read-Host` in your not-listed code, the problem is likely the way that PoSh handles _direct screen writes_ versus _indirect screen writes_. direct ones go directly to the screen, but the indirect ones are delayed while the display system checks to see if they can be grouped. the `*-Host` cmdlets are _direct_ to screen ... the delayed stuff from other cmdlets can result in out-of-sequence display to the screen. [*grin*]

Comment: As @AdminOfThings said, it would be helpful to see more of the code as it works for me as well. Other information that may prove useful is what version of PowerShell you are using. you can collect that by running '$PSVersionTable'. Lastly, is there a reason you are using rounding on the Free Space & then casting the Size? It works either way, just curious why you are doing it differently for each.

Comment: I added the entire loop and removed the sort-object part, and from what I can tell from the comments I need to use a write-host to get it to show up right away. The code is mostly copied from a website which my professor said we can do as long as we link it, which is why some things are a bit weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adjusted your code so now it will output whatever you set in the switch for the chosen item.

I moved the `cls` that was right beneath the `do {` to be outside of that loop and added a [break](https://powershellexplained.com/2018-01-12-Powershell-switch-statement/#break)
command at the end of every switch option. This makes sure that whenever one option is handled, the code exits the switch and does not continue testing the next option.

As for option 2, you need to make sure you sort on a property that is available after the `Select-Object`. Since you created a calculated property by name of `Free Space`, you need to use **that same name** for the Sort-Object cmdlet.

Finally, I removed the `pause` command, because it is redundant.

```
cls
do {
    $input = Read-Host "Select 1-8 (press 9 to quit)"
    switch ($input) {
        '1' {
                cls
                Write-Host "Computer Name:" $env:computername | Select-Object
                Write-Host "OS Version:
                " ([Environment]::OSVersion.VersionString) 
                Write-Host
                break
            }
        '2' { # Modified From: https://www.petri.com/checking-system-drive-free-space-with-wmi-and-powershell
                cls
                Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk | Select-Object DeviceID,
                    @{Name="Size";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}},
                    @{Name="Free Space";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1GB,2)}} | 
                    Sort-Object -Property 'Free Space' | 
                    Format-Table
                break
            }
        '3' { break }
        '4' { break }
        '5' { break }
        '6' { break }
        '7' { break }
        '8' { break }
    }
} while ($input -ne '9')
```

Example output for option 2 on my machine (Dutch number format, so it uses a decimal comma):

> ```
> DeviceID Size Free Space
> -------- ---- ----------
> F:          0          0
> G:          0          0
> C:        233      91,61
> E:        466     309,22
> D:        699     396,05
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, this fixed all the issues.